# Doctrine2 --filter option does not work

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have been trying out Zend Framework 2 out for the purpose of my thesis and workplace and I am using an existing database to build my entities from. I am refactoring the tables one by one.

What I was looking for was an ability to generate a single entity for Module C and exclude other modules. Below is the command I used:

```
 [doctrine-module-bin] orm:convert-mapping  --namespace=Application\Model\Entity --force  --from-database --filter="body_types" annotation ./module/Application/src/
```

1. This command tells me "No metadata classes found" something along those lines if it doesn't trip an error
2. I am using the following directory structure for my entities:

   ```
   |src
      |Application
         |Model
            |Entity
            |Repository
   ```

   My generated entities go to their respective folder and repositories as well but the command line just dumps them at the src directory and below is my configuration:

   ```
   'doctrine' => array(
     'driver' => array(
       'Application_Driver' => array(
          'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
          'cache' => 'array',
          'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Model/Entity')
         ),
        'orm_default' => array(
          'drivers' => array(
              'Application\Model\Entity' => 'Application_Driver'
            ),
         ),
     ),
   ),
   ```

What am I really missing here?